# Chain commands after "IF" Condtitional using &

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, npm-scripts

I am trying to check if a folder has been created IF NOT create the folder

```
IF NOT EXIST dist\\js (MKDIR dist\\js)
```

then regardless if it did or did not create the folder i want to run

```
& uglifyjs dev/*.js -m -o dist/js/app.js
```

now it seems that the **&** is not working. The second command is not executed if the folder exists.

If i use the following as my first statement:

```
IF NOT EXIST dist\\js (MKDIR dist\\js) ELSE (Echo exist)
```

the first time around I run the two together as in:

```
IF NOT EXIST dist\\js (MKDIR dist\\js) ELSE (Echo hate) & echo Love & uglifyjs dev/*.js -m -o dist/js/app.js
```

The folder gets created **BUT** the app.js file is not created.
Only when i run the command again it does create the app.js file.

Now how would i preferably check if theres a folder and then regardless continue with the next command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(IF NOT EXIST dist\\js (MKDIR dist\\js) ELSE (Echo hate)) & echo Love & uglifyjs dev/*.js -m -o dist/js/app.js
```

Parentheses enclose all the code before the `&` to make it operate as 1 complete condition.
Once the condition is done, then the code after the `&` will execute regardless
of the result of the previous condition.

*The doubling up of backslashs are not needed for paths in batch-file as escapes such as `\n` for newline are not a part of the batch-file language.*

Comment: yes escaping the backslashes is for having it in the npm-script.
This way i dont even need the ELSE statement. great.
Thank you